# Issue installing switchboard-plugin-keyboard

Tags: keyboard, switchboard

I'm having an issue with getting the keyboard plugin to work in switchboard.

I've installed both switchboard and switchboard-plugin-keyboard via the terminal with the commands -

sudo apt install switchboard
sudo apt install switchboard switchboard-plugin-keyboard
io.elementary.switchboard (to launch switchboard)

I've also updated and upgraded the apt files and verified both installs and have not been able to figure out whats going wrong. I've pretty new to linux and am not quite sure what to do next.

[image: This is an image of my intended effect.]
The 'Show in Panel' selections are what I'm try to achieve.

[image: not working] 
This is what my keyboard options look like while in switchboard with the keyboard plugin installed.

If anyone could help me figure out whats going on here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Issue solved, I was miss a dependencies and its required branch that enable the feature I was trying to get working.
The dependency that I was missing was the wingpanel-indicator-keyboard.

Simple install: 'sudo apt-get install wingpanel-indicator-keyboard
Go into the indicator's master branch: 'cd wingpanel-indicator-keyboard'
From the master branch you can then pull the needed branch to add:
'git checkout -b raibtoffoletto-master master
git pull git://github.com/raibtoffoletto/wingpanel-indicator-keyboard.git master'
Then build and you normally would with ninja and reboot.